# trouble converting string to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

```
In  [67]:

offline['CREATEDDATE'].head()  
Out[67]:  
0    01/05/06  
1    11/22/03   
2    10/31/07  
3    02/05/10  
4    05/16/05  
Name: CREATEDDATE, dtype: object  
In [68]:

offline['CREATEDDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'])  
In [70]:

offline['CREATEDDATE'].head()  
Out[70]:  
0    01/05/06  
1    11/22/03  
2    10/31/07  
3    02/05/10  
4    05/16/05  
Name: CREATEDDATE, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please wrap code in syntax tags.

Comment: Please try `offline['CREATEDDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'], format='%m/%d/%y')`

Comment: @EdChum this resulted in an even stranger error:  ValueError: time data '1/0/1900' does not match format '%m/%d/%y' (match)

Comment: Try ``'offline['CREATEDDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'].values.flatten())``

Comment: It's possible you have duff data as your sample data works fine without specifying the format string, try `pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'], coerce=True)` it will show 'NaN' where there are invalid str values

Comment: Well `'1/0/1900'` is an invalid format string, what is a `0` month? You can coerce these duff dates to `NaT` or remove them

Comment: @EdChum the coerce function worked. i guess there were rows it couldn't recognize, but didn't throw an error. is this correct? for the next time, how can i see what row caused an error

Comment: Well `pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'], coerce=True).isnull()` will show you only the `NaT` rows you can use this to index into your df: `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(offline['CREATEDDATE'], coerce=True).isnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine. I suggest you to check the version of Pandas and upgrade it if needed.

```
#Check versions. I used 'pandas: 0.16.1', 'numpy: 1.9.2'
pd.show_versions()
df=pd.DataFrame(['01/05/06','11/22/03'], columns=['dates'])
#the format option can be omitted, but I include this for clarity
df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'],format='%m/%d/%y')
df['dates']
#out: Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```